# PayPal REST SDK - how to validate credit card accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, credit-card, paypal-rest-sdk, fraud-prevention

I was able to implement credit card payments on my website. Now my problem is how do I identify if the credit card account is fake or a fraud. What I am doing is I store the credit card info using the vault api then I get those stored accounts for the user to choose what card they will use to purchase my product. However, i can't find a way to add some more validation on how to check if the user is the real user of that credit card account. Right now I can enter any credit card number by just using a card number generator and it directly submits the payment. I can see in my sandbox merchant account that the payment was successful.

So is there a way for me to prevent this?

Thanks to those who could help.

Answer (score 0):

Processing a zero value payment authorization request is the most common way to authenticate the card details are valid without actually taking payment.